# Finding corners from Line arrays

Tags: c#, performance

I have the following code that takes input of `Line` arrays and attempts to find the intersections on the end points between them. The value `_nConrerTolerance` is an `int` of a value of around 10% of the average `Line` length to allow the lines to not need to be exactly on each other. Now obvisouly this code will be quite slow, especially as I have similar methods for top left, bottom left and bottom right corners. Can anyone suggest a way to improve this?

Also if you have any tips on how I can improve my coding style, if needed, that would be great.

```
private Point[] FindTopRightCorners(Line[] horizontalLines, Line[] verticalLines)
{
    List<Point> TopRightCorners = new List<Point>();

    Line[] laHorizontalLines = horizontalLines.OrderByDescending(l => l.EndPoint.X).ThenBy(l => l.EndPoint.Y).ToArray();
    Line[] laVerticalLines = verticalLines.OrderByDescending(l => l.StartPoint.X).ThenBy(l => l.StartPoint.Y).ToArray();

    foreach (Line verticalLine in laVerticalLines)
    {
        foreach (Line horizontalLine in laHorizontalLines)
        {
            if (verticalLine.StartPoint.X >= (horizontalLine.EndPoint.X - _nCornerTolerance) && verticalLine.StartPoint.X <= (horizontalLine.EndPoint.X + _nCornerTolerance))
            {
                if (horizontalLine.EndPoint.Y <= (verticalLine.StartPoint.Y + _nCornerTolerance) && horizontalLine.EndPoint.Y >= (verticalLine.StartPoint.Y - _nCornerTolerance))
                {
                    int nX = Math.Abs((verticalLine.StartPoint.X + horizontalLine.EndPoint.X) / 2);
                    int nY = Math.Abs((verticalLine.StartPoint.Y + horizontalLine.EndPoint.Y) / 2);

                    TopRightCorners.Add(new Point(nX, nY));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return TopRightCorners.Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

And the `Line` class is defined as follows:

```
public class Line
{
    public Point StartPoint { get; private set; }

    public Point EndPoint { get; private set; }

    public Line(Point startPoint, Point endPoint)
    {
        this.StartPoint = startPoint;
        this.EndPoint = endPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample `Line` arrays as input ?

Comment: What determines the value of `_nConrerTolerance` ? Are the vertical lines always equal to the horizontal lines ?

Comment: If you ar eusing C# 6 you don't even need to put `private set` in the properties. C# 6 allows you to set the value of a getter only property in the constructor.

Comment: @denis I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up managing to take about 40-50% of the time off of each loop.

```
private Point[] FindTopLeftCorners(List<Line> horizontalLines, List<Line> verticalLines)
{
    Point[] paHorizontalLines = horizontalLines.OrderBy(l => l.Point1.X)
                                               .ThenBy(l => l.Point1.Y)
                                               .Select(l => l.Point1)
                                               .ToArray();

    Point[] paVerticalLines = verticalLines.OrderBy(l => l.Point1.X)
                                           .ThenBy(l => l.Point1.Y)
                                           .Select(l => l.Point1)
                                           .ToArray();

   List<Point> plTopLeftCorners = new List<Point>();
    for (int vi = 0, vc = paVerticalLines.Length, hi = 0, hc = 0; vi < vc; ++vi)
    {
        for (hi = 0, hc = paHorizontalLines.Length; hi < hc; ++hi)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(paVerticalLines[vi].X - paHorizontalLines[hi].X) <= _nCornerTolerance
             && Math.Abs(paVerticalLines[vi].Y - paHorizontalLines[hi].Y) <= _nCornerTolerance)
            {
                plTopLeftCorners.Add(new Point((paVerticalLines[vi].X + paHorizontalLines[hi].X) / 2,
                                               (paVerticalLines[vi].Y + paHorizontalLines[hi].Y) / 2));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return AverageNearbyPoints(plTopLeftCorners.Distinct().ToArray(), true, true);
}
```

Essentially the biggest change is selecting the point to be used in the initial order statement instead of the full line. The other changes are going to a for loops and various other memory allocation changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have similar code and similar performance issue in your other question about points instead of lines.  [I answered that one here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124378/finding-the-nearby-points-from-an-array/124414#124414). Some of my answers can apply here particularly as to the repeated use of `.ToArray()`?

If you skipped everything as arrays and went with `IEnumerable<Line>` or `IEnumerable<Point>` for inputs, output, and anything inbetween then you might see some performance benefit.  Might.  Don't know until you run it.  But sounds like you are talking about big collections.

If you try using `IEnumerable` and things are still slow, I'd try to use `Parallel.For` with a [range partitioner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner(v=vs.110).aspx).

That should address your major concern.  On a minor concern, the `Line` class is good enough and looks like something I once wrote.  I eventually switched from `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` to `Point1` and `Point2` since some readers may think `StartPoint` should somehow be 'less than' when compared to `EndPoint` or that it should be drawn like a vector that somehow starts at `StartPoint` and is then drawn to `EndPoint`.  To avoid such needless notions, I went with the generic `Point1` and `Point2`.

Comment: Sounds like a good decision on the `Line` class and I can give that a go too. But with the threading, I was hoping to try and cut the time down initially and then move to threading, that way I know I've got it working as best I can.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The problem with parallel threading is you could just as easily degrade performance rather than improve it.  It all depends upon how many lines you have.  How big are your horiztonalLines and verticalLines?

Comment: I'm trying to improve the performance of these four methods before I even look into multithreading anyway. Seeing as the four put together take up about 60% of the total time of the full process. And it depends they can be from a few hundred all the way up to a few thousand. There can even be none, but we hope that won't happen!